# Repayment of an order

Tags: magento-1.7, payment, payment-gateway, payment-methods

Sometimes when my customers places order they don't make the payment but they would later ask how to make a payment for the order which is already placed and not paid for.

Is there a way my customers would be able to make payments for orders which they have not paid yet?

I searched everywhere but was not able to find any solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a reorder button on the my account screen? However this will create a new order in Magento which the customer can checkout. The advantage of this is that you can see all cancelled orders in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it all depends on what payment gateways you have configured.

With most (if not all) you would have to confirm the payment manually.

For example with paypal you could give the customers your paypal address and tell them to reference the order number when paying. When you receive payment you could then manually change the order status and process the order.

The same would apply for bank transfers.